# php While-loop returns a single sql row instead of multiple

Tags: php, mysql

I want my code to check every row from a sql table. I used a while loop for this as it should check on every row in the sql table. Instead it only looks at the first row and doesn't go any further than that. The if statement and update query do work. The while loop just doesn't go any further than row one. Even if the second select query i used returns 9 rows.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT curdate() FROM promocode");
            $stmt->execute();
            $row = $stmt->fetch();
            $currentdate = $row["curdate()"];



            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT BeginDatum, EindDatum, Gebruikt, MaxGebruikt, PromocodeID FROM promocode");
            $stmt->execute();


            while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
                if ($currentdate >= $row["BeginDatum"] && $currentdate <= $row["EindDatum"] && $row["Gebruikt"] < $row["MaxGebruikt"]) {
                    $actief = "yes";
                } else {
                    $actief = "no";
                }
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE promocode SET Actief=? WHERE PromocodeID=?");
                $stmt->execute(array($actief, $row["PromocodeID"]));
            }
```

Comment: You're overwriting `$stmt` in your loop.

Comment: @mario is correct. I think you can use $stmt->fetchAll and assign it to a variable, then loop through that variable instead of doing what you're doing